# Discord tasks.loop, task doesn't loop

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot, and I need something to loop every 10 seconds. I've tried following some tutorials, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import asyncio
import passwords


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.');



@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def name_of_function():
    print("looped")


client.run(passwords.token)
```

The token and such are working fine, I just have them in another file. When I run this, nothing happens. It never prints `looped`, and I've been letting it run for up to 10 minutes. What am I doing wrong, and why won't this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually start the loop as well, using `name_of_function.start()`. Make sure to put this *before* `client.run()`, as otherwise it will never be called either.